# Fastest way to determine average of gridded values within a given radius of a point

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array of values.  Each element in the array represents a grid point from a grid where each box is 13km on a side.  I need to determine the average value of all points within 50 miles of a specific point on the grid.

My current solution determines a bounding box and then references items in the array within that box using their indices, which is slow with numpy.  I'm trying to determine a faster solution.

Current solution:

```
num_x = 400        #horizontal dimension of the 2D array
num_y = 300        #vertical dimension of the 2D array
num_dx = 6         #maximum number of horizontal grid points that fit within 50 miles
num_dy = 6         #same as above but for vertical (square grid)
radius_m = 80467.2 #50 miles expressed in meters
values = []        # stores the extracted values

for ix in range(-num_dx,num_dx+1):
    for jy in range(-num_dy,num_dy+1):
        # Determine distance to this point
        dist = ((ix*dx)**2+(jy*dy)**2)**0.5
        if dist <= radius_m:
            # Ensure this grid point actually exists within the grid
            if (j+jy) < num_y and (i+ix) < num_x:
                value = myarray[i+ix,j+jy]
                    if value is not masked and value >= 0:
                        values.append(float(value))

average = sum(values) / float(len(values))
```

This is slow (takes about 1.5 seconds) due to accessing myarray over 100 times to extract the value of a single element.  Is there a vector method that would work better here?  I can't seem to figure out a way to do this with a mask since the conditional is based on the location of the grid point relative to another, not the value of the element itself.

Comment: Why aren't you slicing the array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: Think of it this way: For every point on a circle there are 3 other points that have exactly the same magnitude but differing signs on the components.

Comment: does the functionality in https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/examples.py look like it will solve you problem? Seems like a single line of the form group_by(radius).mean(myarray) would work, and you wouldn't just get the 50 mile ring, but all of them for the same discounted price.

Comment: @TheOx is using scipy an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't runable and seems to contain a bug for when `i < num_dx` or `j < num_dy` (then it wraps around to the other side of the array). But making some assumptions on your variable names, this is how I would do it:

```
# First make sure we stay in the grid
i1, i2 = max(i-num_dx, 0), min(i+num_dx+1, num_x)
j1, j2 = max(j-num_dy, 0), min(j+num_dy+1, num_y)

# Get the radius in blocks, grid should be homogeneous
radius_i = radius_m / 13000.0

# Calc distances per element by broadcasting
DX = np.arange(i1, i2) - i
DY = np.arange(j1, j2)[:, None] - j
mask = DX*DX + DY*DY <= radius_i*radius_i

# Get block of interest and apply mask
values = myarray[i1:i2, j1:j2][mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

For interior points (where the radius doesn't extend outside your image), you can just compute a single mask that is used for any interior point. Start with an array of zeros:

```
mask = np.zeros((2 * num_dx + 1, 2 * num_dy + 1), dtype=np.int)
```

Assuming your point of interest is at the center of that array, set each element that falls within the radius to 1 (not shown here). Then,

```
indices = np.argwhere(mask.ravel() == 1)
```

Then for any interior element `(i, j)` in `myarray`, you would get the values within the radius like:

```
values = myarray[i-num_dx: i+num_dx+1, j-num_dy: j+num_dy+1].ravel()[indices]
```

For points near the border, you would make a copy of `mask` and set rows/cols outside the image to zero before setting `indices`.